# Não sei como chamar um certo item da lista que entrar no meu "for" em outras funções

Tags: java, data, lista

Estou tentando fazer um programa que pega uma lista de sócios que contem o nome, email, e dia de renovação(tipo dia de pagar mensalidade), e quando for o dia, manda um e-mail para ele.

Porém estou com problema em pegar o nome e e-mail daquele determinado sócio que estiver no dia de mandar o e-mail. Tentei usar `socio[i]`(que é o nome da lista), que é o numero que entrou no `for`.

No meu `if`, não estou conseguindo comparar `day_of_month` com o data, data é `integer` e pelo que me parece `day_of_month` é de outro tipo.

Segue meu código para ver se ajuda a entender meu problema

```
 package trabalho2;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import org.apache.commons.mail.DefaultAuthenticator;
import org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException;
import org.apache.commons.mail.SimpleEmail;

public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList <Socios> socios = new ArrayList();
    //cadastrando os sócios
    Socios socios1 = new Socios("Mateus", "mateus@hotmail.com", 11);
    Socios socios2 = new Socios("Eduardo Moya Simões", "eduardo@hotmail.com", 11);
//isso aqui é tipo colocando o q foi cadastrado na lista
    socios.add(socios1);
    socios.add(socios2);


    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();

    SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail();
    email.setSSLOnConnect(true);
    email.setHostName("smtp.googlemail.com");
    email.setSslSmtpPort("465");
    email.setAuthenticator( new DefaultAuthenticator( "sociotorcedor@novaandradina.org" , "nossasenha"));


    for (int i = 0; i < socios.size(); i++) {
        //isso só serve para vc ver como ta funcionando, depois tem q apagar
        System.out.println("Socio: " + socios.get(i));

        System.out.println(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) = socios(i).getData) {

            // função manda e-mail

        try {
          email.setFrom( "pogramasociotorcedor@novaandradina.org", "Socio torcedor");

            email.setDebug(true);

          email.setSubject( "Pagamento fatura");
          email.setMsg("Salve dpoente\n tu tem q pagar sua mensalidade né jumento");
          email.addTo(socios.getEmail, socios.getNome);

          email.send();
          System.out.println("Email enviado para: " + socios.getEmail +" de " + socios.getNome);
     }catch (EmailException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
        }
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seu código tem vários problemas. Entre eles:

### Problemas no if

O incidente está na seguinte linha:

```
if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) = socios(i).getData)
```

Os problemas são:

- Você está usando o [operador](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html) `=` ao invés de `==`. O primeiro é usado para assinalar, enquanto o segundo é usado para comparação de igualdade.
- Você está usando uma sintaxe inválida para buscar os itens de `socios`. O correto é usar o método [ArrayList#get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get(int)). Inclusive você usou da forma correta para testar se estava funcionando...
- Pelo nome, suponho que `socios(i).getData` seja uma chamada de método. A sintaxe do Java obriga o uso de parêntesis.

Tudo junto, ficaria:

```
if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == socios.get(i).getData())
```

### Uso de métodos inexistentes

Em vários lugares do fonte, usa-se métodos como:

```
socios.getEmail
```

Os problemas são:

- A lista `socios` não possui tais métodos. Primeiro, é preciso acessar um item da lista com Array#get.
- Uso de parêntesis é mandatório para invocação de métodos, conforme supracitado.

### Conclusões

Esse tipos de erro podem ser evitados com o uso de uma boa IDE e principalmente com conhecimento sobre a linguagem.

Sinto que uma boa estudada sobre Java iria te beneficiar bastante, recomendo que o faça. Os [tutoriais da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) são um bom começo.

Inclusive se quiser melhorar seu código, procure uma pequena joia chamada foreach.

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito mas me ajude no seguinte:

Comment: @jãoassacino Ajudar no que?

Comment: Obrigado, me ajudou muito mas me ajude no seguinte: "socios.getEmail
Os problemas são: A lista socios não possui tais métodos." na verdade eu criei outra classe chamada socios com as variaveis email, nome, e data e adicionei os gets e sets. Sobre 'socios(i)', socios é uma lista, se vc observar no 'for (int i = 0; i < socios.size(); i++)' a intenção é passar por aqui todas as listas, assim 'socios' é o nome e o 'i' é a contagem;

Comment: quando ele entra nesse 'if' a intençao é pegar a lista com aquele **i**; por exemplo, no for passou a lista socios3, no if então quando eu digo: 'if (c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) = socios(i).getData)' eu estou querendo testar o socios 3

Comment: eu estava escrevendo, kkkkk

Answer (score 0):

Aparentemente existem alguns erros no código.

Sua comparação está faltando um `=` e se o `getData` é um método, está faltando parênteses `() [.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH) == socios(i).getData()]`

No mais, tudo parece estar correto.